# How to split dash-separated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date saved in an `nvarchar` type and I want to split the day, month and year into separate `nvarchar` variables (that means three variables). The date looks as follows: `exposure_date ='2018-12-04'` and the format is `yyyy-dd-mm`
any help please?

My whole project is stuck on this.

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a format. If you're storing your dates with the "format" `yyyy-dd-MM` this means you're storing them as a `varchar(10)`. Quite simply: don't. Store dates as what they are, a `date`.

Comment: If you then do store your dates as the correct datatype, you can then make use of the [`DATEPART`] function. This is effectively as XY Problem. The problem you are trying to solve is to split different parts of a string to solve the problem of getting the parts of the date (Problem Y), however, the real problem is that you are using the wrong data type )Problem X), and using the correct one makes the solution trivial.

Comment: "I have a date saved in an `nvarchar` type" There's your problem. Dates should be stored as Dates, not as strings.

Comment: Seems i forgot to actually link [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" answer here is to fix your datatype. When storing data always choose an appropriate data type for the data you're storing. For a date (with no time part) then the correct datatype is `date`. if you're storing numerical data, then use a numerical datatype, such as `int` or `decimal`. `(n)varchar` is **not** a one size fits all datatype and using it to store data that has a data type designed for it is almost always a bad choice. *I'm storing the data as an `(n)varchar` because I need it in a specific format* is never an excuse; have your presentation layer handle to display format, not your RDBMS.

The first step, therefore would be to change your string representation `yyyy-dd-MM` of a date to the ISO format `yyyyMMdd` by doing:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET exposure_date = LEFT(exposure_date,4) + RIGHT(exposure_date,2) + SUBSTRING(exposure_date,6,2);
```

Now you have a unambiguous representation, you can change the data type of your column without concerns of incorrect implicit casts or error:

```
ALTER YourTable ALTER COLUMN exposure_date date;
```

Then, finally, you can treat your data as what it is, a date, and use the `DATEPART` function:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,exposure_date) AS Exposure_Year,
       DATEPART(MONTH,exposure_date) AS Exposure_Month,
       DATEPART(DAY,exposure_date) AS Exposure_Day
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select  concat(cast(year(cast('2018-12-04' as date)) as varchar(4)),'-', 
cast(month(cast('2018-12-04' as date)) as varchar(2)), '-',
cast(day(cast('2018-12-04' as date)) as varchar(2)))
from tablename
```

Comment: The OP is using a `varchar` to store the dates, and is using the format `yyyy-dd-MM`. Simply using `cast` could convert the value `'2018-12-04'` to the date `20181204`, which is not correct.

Comment: Have you checked with values like 2018-13-04 it will produce conversion error.

Comment: @fa06 thank you a bunch! that worked yay! and what if I wanna concatinate them now? I wanna regroup them together but I want the format to become yyyy-mm-dd that means the 2018-12-04 will become 2018-04-12 and store it in a variable

Comment: you can use concat() function

Comment: @fa06 when I add this line select CONCAT(yr, mon,dy); SQL doesn't recognize yr, mon and dy variables

Comment: @fa06 the date now shows up like this "2018124" and not "2018-04-12". no dashes, no 0 before the 4 and the format didn't change it was 2018-12-04 and now it's not 2018-04-12

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following

```
Declare @myDate date 
select @myDate= Cast(substring('2011-29-12', 1, 4) 
+ '-' + substring('2011-29-12', 9, 2)
+ '-' + substring('2011-29-12', 6, 2)
as Date)   --YYYY-MM-DD

Select @myDate as DateTime,
           datename(day,@myDate) as Date,
           month(@myDate) as Month,
           datename(year,@myDate) as Year,
           Datename(weekday,@myDate) as DayName
```

The output is as shown below

```
DateTime    Date    Month   Year    DayName
--------------------------------------------
2011-29-12  29      12      2011    Thursday
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/UKZK74683)

Comment: The OP specifically states they have the format `yyyy-dd-MM`, not `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed format, then you could use this simple query with `substring` method:

```
select substring(dt, 1, 4) + '-' +
       substring(dt, 9, 2) + '-' +
       substring(dt, 6, 2) [YYYY-MM-DD]
from (values ('2018-31-12')) tbl(dt)
```

Comment: thank you a bunch! that worked yay! and what if I wanna concatinate them now? I wanna regroup them together but I want the format to become yyyy-mm-dd that means the 2018-12-04 will become 2018-04-12 and store it in a variable

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi See updated answer, if answer helped you you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go directly to the main issue, which is you are using the wrong datatype to store dates, you should store them as `DATE`, the datatypes are there for a reason and you need to choose a proper one for your column.

So, you need to *ALTER* your table and change the column datatype to `DATE` instead of `NVARCHAR` datatype.

```
ALTER <Table Name Here>
ALTER COLUMN <Column Name Here> DATE;
```

Then all things will easy, you just run the following query to get the desired output

```
SELECT YEAR(<Column Name Here>) TheYear,
       MONTH(<Column Name Here>) TheMonth,
       DAY(<Column Name Here>) TheDay
FROM <Table Name Here>
```

Which is the right and the best solution.

You can also (if you are not going to alter your table) do as

```
CREATE TABLE Dates(
  StrDate NVARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Dates VALUES
(N'2018-12-04'),
(N'Invalid');

SELECT LEFT(StrDate, 4) StrYear,
       SUBSTRING(StrDate, 6, 2) StrMonth,
       RIGHT(StrDate, 2) StrDay
FROM Dates;
```

OR

```
SELECT YEAR(StrDate) StrYear,
       MONTH(StrDate) StrMonth,
       DAY(StrDate) StrDay
FROM (
       SELECT TRY_CAST(StrDate AS DATE) StrDate
       FROM Dates
     )T
```